# drupal custom callback in node edit form is not firing

Tags: nodes, hooks, ajax

i am fairly new to drupal  , i have custom button added to one the content type edit page , when i click on that button i want to call a function but it seems like it is not calling function when i see the console i see drupa ajax error coming whenever i click the button . please let me know what i am doing wrong here .

```
function mymodule_form_node_program_edit_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['apply'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Apply'),
    '#weight' => '9',
    '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#ajax'                     => array(
      'callback' => 'button_test_callback',
    ),
  );
}
    function button_test_callback(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  echo '<script>alert("Welcome")</script>';
  return $form;
}
```

error i am getting :

Uncaught
Drupal.AjaxError {message: "\nAn AJAX HTTP error occurred.\nHTTP Result Code: 50…\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)\n", name: "AjaxError"}
message: "\nAn AJAX HTTP error occurred.\nHTTP Result Code: 500\nDebugging information follows.\nPath: /node/680911/edit?destination=/admin/content&ajax_form=1\nStatusText: error\nResponseText: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormAjaxResponseBuilder->buildResponse() (line 67 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormAjaxResponseBuilder.php). Drupal\Core\Form\EventSubscriber\FormAjaxSubscriber->onException(Object, 'kernel.exception', Object)\ncall_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.exception', Object) (Line: 111)\nDrupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', Object) (Line: 227)\nSymfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleException(Object, Object, 1) (Line: 79)\nSymfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 67)\nDrupal\simple_oauth\HttpMiddleware\BasicAuthSwap->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)\nDrupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)\nDrupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)\nDrupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)\nDrupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 49)\nAsm89\Stack\Cors->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)\nDrupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)\nDrupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)\nDrupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)\nStack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)\nDrupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an D7 callback definition. It needs to be defined as a D8+ callback. So this:

```
function button_test_callback($form, &$form_state) {
```

Should be this:

```
function button_test_callback(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
```

Comment: i change to this still getting the same error , it seems the function button_test_callback is not getting called

Comment: I updated the code, it was missing a forwarrd slash, so you should try the updated code. Also, what file is `button_test_callback()` in?

Comment: it is still not working , the button_test_callback is in the same file. i want change the value of node field when i click the custom button in the node edit form with out submitting the node edit form

Comment: "in the same file" <- What file is that?

Comment: it is the custom module file , course_program.module

Comment: Ok, that should work then. Please update the original post to show your current code.

Comment: i updated the code , i am getting Uncaught Drupal.AjaxError  as i mentioned in the question whenever i am clicking the button .

Comment: If that's your current code, you need to return a value from the ajax callback.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: To test, add `return $form;` to your ajax callback.

Comment: i added the return $form and i updated the code in the question too , but still not firing the function i am still getting the ajax error in console

Comment: That `echo` call may be causing you issues. Did you try without that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128913/discussion-between-vyshnavi-and-jaypan).

Comment: hii jaypan , after reomving echo the error is not popping up
but i want to change the field value $form['field_text_plain']['widget'][0]['value']['#value'] = '75433g'; but it not showing
do i need to send the value in return ?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers - it's a one-question one-answer format site. The question of your empty callback has been solved, and therefore question you just asked is a new question. Please mark this question as solved, and then open a new topic for that issue.

Comment: ohh sure , thank you for your help :)